# Multi-threading on for loop with mutation operations in julia

Tags: multithreading, for-loop, julia

I am trying to run the below mentioned code `for loop` using `@threads` for multi-threading, however the results always portray an error of mismatching number of outputs.

```
using Combinatorics, Base.Threads
import Base.Threads.@threads
func(x, y)
result = Float64[]
a = Float64[]
@threads for c in combinations(1:n, 2)
        a, b = c
        result = func(a, b)
        push!(result, result)
        push!(a, a)     
     end
```

The error observed during the processing:

```
DimensionMismatch("column :result has length 60 and column :a has length 50")
```

Please suggest an approach which make sure that no mutations from the loop are missed.

Comment: There are a number of problems in your example: putting obvious name collisions aside (global `a` vs local `a`, global `result` vs local `result), `Combinatorics.combinations` produces an object on which I don't think `Base.threads` knows how to iterate. So I wonder how you even got to the point where race conditions would happen.

Comment: Also, when you refer to "I/O operations" in the title of you question, are you actually referring to the `push!` operations on your vectors? If so, these are not I/O, but rather mutations

Comment: @FrançoisFévotte thanks for the correction, i have changed the title to mutations.

Comment: @FrançoisFévotte, Thanks for the feedback, I will try to resolve the code as per the suggestion and will update once i find the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that does not work in your example is that all threads are mutating (*via* `push!`) the same vectors (`result` and `a`) possibly concurrently, thereby allowing race conditions to happen.

One way around this would be to have a collection of vectors (one per thread); each thread only modifies its own vector (identified by it `threadid()`).

With such a technique, a simplified version of your example could look like this:

```
# The function we want to apply to each element
julia> f(x) = 2x+1
f (generic function with 1 method)

# Two collections of vectors (one vector for each thread)
# that will hold the results for each thread
julia> results = [Float64[] for _ in 1:Threads.nthreads()];
julia> as      = [Float64[] for _ in 1:Threads.nthreads()]
8-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []

julia> Threads.@threads for a in 1:10
           result = f(a)

           # Each thread only ever mutates its own result vector: 
           #    results[Threads.threadid()]
           push!(results[Threads.threadid()], result)
           push!(as[Threads.threadid()],      a)
       end
```

Note that you'll get a collection of results, indexed by the id of the thread that produced them.

```
# Now you get a collection of results, indexed by the id of the thread which produced them
julia> results
8-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [3.0, 5.0]  # These results have been produced by thread #1
 [7.0, 9.0]
 [11.0]
 [13.0]
 [15.0]
 [17.0]
 [19.0]
 [21.0]

julia> as
8-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [1.0, 2.0]
 [3.0, 4.0]
 [5.0]
 [6.0]
 [7.0]
 [8.0]
 [9.0]
 [10.0]
```

In the end, you therefore need to concatenate or flatten all resulting vectors in some way in order to combine all thread-specific results into one. One way would be to concatenate all results (which will allocate a new, large vector to hold all results):

```
julia> reduce(vcat, results)
10-element Vector{Float64}:
  3.0
  5.0
  7.0
  9.0
 11.0
 13.0
 15.0
 17.0
 19.0
 21.0

julia> reduce(vcat, as)
10-element Vector{Float64}:
  1.0
  2.0
  3.0
  4.0
  5.0
  6.0
  7.0
  8.0
  9.0
 10.0
```

Another way would be to directly iterate on the nested results, flattening them on the fly (so as not to allocate double the memory to store them in a flat fashion):

```
julia> using Base.Iterators: flatten

julia> for r in flatten(results)
           println(r)
       end
3.0
5.0
7.0
9.0
11.0
13.0
15.0
17.0
19.0
21.0

julia> for (a, r) in zip(flatten(as), flatten(results))
           println("$a -> $r")
       end
1.0 -> 3.0
2.0 -> 5.0
3.0 -> 7.0
4.0 -> 9.0
5.0 -> 11.0
6.0 -> 13.0
7.0 -> 15.0
8.0 -> 17.0
9.0 -> 19.0
10.0 -> 21.0
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation @FrançoisFévotte, Highly appreciated!! I have tried this approach and it works.