# How to efficiently parallelize accumulation task in Julia using @threads?

Tags: multithreading, julia

I'm new to multithreading. I am trying to do an accumulation task in Julia, similar to the following:

```
a = collect(1:5)
b = 0.0
for i = 1:5
    b += a[6-i] + i
end
```

I would like to parallelize this using @threads, but when I do

```
a = collect(1:5)
b = 0.0
Threads.@threads for i = 1:5
    b += a[6-i] + i
end
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: TaskFailedException
> Stacktrace:
> [1] wait
> @ ./task.jl:345 [inlined]
> [2] threading_run(fun::var"#263#threadsfor_fun#57"{var"#263#threadsfor_fun#56#58"{UnitRange{Int64}}}, static::Bool)
> Base.Threads ./threadingconstructs.jl:38
> [3] top-level scope
> @ ./threadingconstructs.jl:89
>
> nested task error: UndefVarError: b not defined
> Stacktrace:
> [1] macro expansion
> @ ./REPL[35]:2 [inlined]
> [2] #263#threadsfor_fun#56
> @ ./threadingconstructs.jl:84 [inlined]
> [3] #263#threadsfor_fun
> @ ./threadingconstructs.jl:51 [inlined]
> [4] (::Base.Threads.var"#1#2"{var"#263#threadsfor_fun#57"{var"#263#threadsfor_fun#56#58"{UnitRange{Int64}}}, Int64})()
> Base.Threads ./threadingconstructs.jl:30

What is the correct way to go about parallelizing this task? All of the math I will be doing is isolated and lends itself to multithreading, but I ultimately need to accumulate the output from the threads into a single variable.

I have tried making a `vector` as long as the number of computations I will be doing, but I also need this method to scale so this doesn't seem like the right solution.

Another idea I came across [in this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65714244/multi-threading-on-for-loop-with-mutation-operations-in-julia) was to make a vector equal in length to the number of threads and index the vector using `Threads.nthreads()`. This seems to work fine, but I still wanted to see if this is a suitable method or if I should consider other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the sums into subsums on a per-thread basis with `Threads.nthreads()` and `Threads.threadid()` to avoid clashes on the b variable:

```
julia> barray = zeros(Int, Threads.nthreads())
6-element Vector{Int64}:
0
0
0
0
0
0

julia> @Threads.threads for i = 1:5
        barray[Threads.threadid()] += a[6-i] + i
    end

julia> b = sum(barray)
30
```

NB: This works because the subsequent sums do not depend on the prior ones. If this condition of independence between threads is not met (it is not generally met with the accumulate() function) this method does not work, and you would need a lock and probably would not gain as much by threading.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation at the end! I had considered a lock too and was concerned that the waiting for resources would eliminate any speedup.

Answer (score 0):

There are also various packages which will do threaded reduction, for example:

```
julia> using Tullio  # mine, recursively sub-divides 1:5

julia> @tullio b := a[6-i] + i
30

julia> using ThreadsX  # TKF, built on folds

julia> ThreadsX.sum(1:5) do i
         a[6-i] + i
       end
30

julia> using LoopVectorization  # re-writes loop, using Polyester.jl

julia> let b = 0.0
         @tturbo for i = 1:5
           b += a[6-i] + i
         end
         b
       end
30.0
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Are all of these packages maintained? Do you have any preferences?